# Masking Text Input

Tags: jquery

I have a text input box and need to mask the input with "X" whatever the user enters.
Is there any way it can be achieved using jQuery. We are using struts2 in our application.  Thanks

Comment: An actual X? Why not use `type=password` and mask it with the standardized `*`?

Answer (score 7):

Use `type=password` to mask the input typed by the user.

```
<input type="password" .../>
```

I think in struts 2 you have a tag for it.

```
<s:password .. />
```

**Passord field:** http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/password.html

Comment: my input is a text and not password

Comment: @user1096909 Is there a reason why you cannot use `password` field? It behaves same as textfield except that it masks the entered characters.

Comment: the text field should display only 'X' instead of '*'